# Carregar valores de um SelectItem já gravado em banco na tela

Tags: java, jsf

Estou com um problema para carregar o valor selecionado no `<f:selectItem>` pelo usuário
quando renderiza fica desse jeito:

`<option value="320">Coordenador Desenvolvimento</option>`

eu queria que fosse setado o atributo `selected="selected"`

**Segue meu xhtml:**

```
<div class="span3">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="txttecnicosselecionaveis" required="true" 
                     requiredMessage="Selecione o tecnico responsável pelo cliente" 
                     binding="#{cadastradorCliente.txtTecnicosSelecionaveis}" disabled="#{cadastradorCliente.desabilitarCampos}" styleClass="span12">
        <f:selectItems value="#{cadastradorCliente.tecnicosSelecionaveis}" 
                       itemLabel="#{cliente.tecnico.nome}" itemValue="#{cliente.tecnico.id}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
```

**Meu MB onde eu recupero os dados**

```
public String actSelecionarTabela()
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession sessao = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

    if (sessao != null) 
    {
        sessao = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        sessao.setAttribute("cliente", cliente);
    }

    txtCnpj.setValue(cliente.getCnpj());
    txtRazaoSocial.setValue(cliente.getRazaoSocial());
    txtNomeFantasia.setValue(cliente.getNomeFantasia());
    txtInscricaoEstadual.setValue(cliente.getInscricaoEstadual());
    txtSite.setValue(cliente.getSite());

    txtEndereco.setValue(cliente.getEndereco().getDescricao());
    txtResponsavel.setValue(cliente.getResponsavel().getNome());
    txtTelefone.setValue(cliente.getResponsavel().getContato().getTelefone());
    txtEmail.setValue(cliente.getResponsavel().getContato().getEmail());
    txtCemail.setValue(cliente.getResponsavel().getContato().getCemail());
    txtAtivo.setValue(cliente.isAtivo());       
    txtTecnicosSelecionaveis.setValue(cliente.getTecnico().getCodigo());
    txtGerentesSelecionaveis.setValue(cliente.getGerente().getCodigo());
```

Quando eu retorno os dados salvos na tela volta assim meu selectItem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que voltasse já carregado os valores que foram selecionados na primeira vez
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o resultado dos dados salvos em banco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de diversas formas e não consigo resolver isso, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: "eu queria que fosse setado o atributo selected="selected" - Não entendi.

Comment: Exemplo eu ja cadastrei em banco com o id do selectItem, porem eu quero carregar na tela de volta os dados para o usuário conseguir editar, eu consigo recuperar em tela todos os dados do cadastro menos o meu item selecionado

Comment: Que tal publicar no bean uma propriedade que retorne o item selecionado, e então setar o atributo "value" do componente apontando para esta propriedade `<h:selectOneMenu value="#{cadastradorCliente.tecnicoSelecionado}">`?

Comment: @Caffé meus retornos até o xhtml estão voltando o value correto, o problema é quando eu clico para selecionar na tela e dispara meu actionListener 

"txtTecnicosSelecionaveis.setValue(cliente.getTecnico().getCodigo());"

Ele me traz o código que foi salvo ele somente não carrega na tela :(

Comment: Imagino que o problema não seja apenas exibição, mas que você também não conseguiu ainda salvar no banco um item selecionado na página (inseriu no banco por outro meio). Certo?

Comment: Consigo, eu salvo o id e nome do tecnico e gerente selecionados , consigo alterar também esses dados por meio da aplicação.
Ele apenas não exibe :(

Comment: "o problema é quando eu clico para selecionar na tela e dispara meu actionListener..." Bem, eu realmente não consegui entender o problema. Boa sorte aí!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando incluir a propriedade `value` no `selectOneMenu`.

Por exemplo, se o seu *managed bean* possui a propriedade `tecnicoResponsavel` indicando o técnico previamente selecionado você pode fazer algo assim:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="txttecnicosselecionaveis" required="true" 
                     requiredMessage="Selecione o tecnico responsável pelo cliente" 
                     binding="#{cadastradorCliente.txtTecnicosSelecionaveis}"
                     disabled="#{cadastradorCliente.desabilitarCampos}" 
                     <!-- Carrega id do tecnico responsavel -->
                     value="#{cadastradorCliente.tecnicoResponsavel.id}"
                     styleClass="span12">
```

Para que determinado item venha pré-selecionado o `value` do `selectOneMenu` deve bater com o `itemValue` do `selectItems` (nesse caso, `#{cliente.tecnico.id}`)

---

**Fontes**:

1. [SOen - JSF: default selection for `<f:selectItem>` within `<h:selectOneMenu>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337101/664577)
2. [SOen - JSF f:selectItems set item selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337101/664577).

Comment: era isso mesmo cara, ainda estou engatinhando em desenvolvimento, muito obrigado.

Comment: Opa, agradeça ao [@Caffé](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14584/caff%c3%a9), só vi [o comentário dele](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48025/carregar-valores-de-um-selectitem-j%c3%a1-gravado-em-banco-na-tela#comment96863_48025) agora.

Comment: @Caffé muito obrigado pela ajuda acabei esquecendo de você!.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino O que o Anthony quis dizer é que esta mesma sugestão eu já tinha feito nos comentários, logo no comecinho da nossa conversa. Sucesso aí!

Comment: @Caffé me desculpe, eu não tinha entendido a sua sugestão, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Caffé pode me tirar uma dúvida? ontem eu achei que tinha solucionado o problema eu criei uma propriedade(String) no meu MB que recebe o tecnico selecionado que vem do banco após a gravação, já realizei um debugue e as variaveis estão sendo preenchidas, porém na hora de renderizar ainda não aparece no SelecTOneMenu.